# Dismissing a non-animated UIViewController from an embed UITableView causing performance issue(seems to be delayed more than 200ms) sometimes

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

#### Summary

When dismissing a presented UIViewController from an embed UITableView by selecting the cell without any animation(animated:false), I believe usually it causes under 50ms but sometimes(1~2 out of 10 times) it will cause more than 200ms so that user can feel the performance impact(an obvious delay). The testing project and the log is uploaded below.

#### Test Environment:

- macOS 10.14.6
- iOS 12 & 13
- Xcode 11.3(11C29)

#### Steps to Reproduce: (from testing project)

1. Run the app
2. Tap 'Button' button
3. Tap any cell from the presented UITableView(which is actually embed in a UIViewController)
4. The presented UIViewController is dismissed

#### Expected Results:

in step 4, the UIViewController is dismissed within 50ms(as usual) every time and no obvious performance delay/lag(?) happens

#### Actual Results:

in step 4, 1~2 out of 10 times(10%~20% chance) the UIViewController is dismissed by more than 200ms and user can feel an obvious performance delay/lag

The testing project is below:
https://github.com/inexcii/issue-dismiss-presented-tableview

Does anyone experience the same issue and if yes, what's your workaround?

by the way, I've already opened a bug-report to Apple and an [open-radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/FB7531120).

Comment: When you touch a cell it always takes time to respond because there are so many gestures this could be.

Comment: @matt hi, thank you for the respond. So you mean it is normal(happens in most apps) rather than a performance issue from UIKit? For testing, I only used a very simple 'a short click' gesture rather than others like long pressing, touch-up-outside, etc. and still got the results.

Comment: Did Apple respond to your bug report? Dismissing a UIViewController that was presented as a popover always takes at least 200ms for me (non-animated), which is a ridiculous amount of time. During this chunk of time, the main thread is not blocked, however, no touch events get reported. This is definitely a performance/structural issue in UIKit.

Comment: @Keiwan hi, thank you for the respond. Apple does not reply anything to me after more than half a year... I pushed it again. I agree with you but I think that's the situation here...good luck.